# SQL Server 2016 deprecation of DML keyword ROWGUIDCOL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, deprecation

I just found out that the DML keyword `ROWGUIDCOL` is deprecated, replacement is `$rowguid`; and that DML `IDENTITYCOL` keyword is deprecated, new name is `$identity`.

I don't understand why a non-variable (no dollar sign symbol) DML can be replaced with what is essentially an alias, which if I understand it, will sometimes evaluate back to `ROWGUIDCOL` and sometimes to something else?. Can anyone explain what is going on here? What does this deprecation mean?

In AdventureWorks sample, for example, I don't think it means I should do this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Sales].[Customer]
(
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    ...
    [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] $rowguid  NOT NULL,
    ...
);
GO
```

The above doesn't work obviously. So what is it saying is deprecated? Clearly not the keyword `ROWGUIDCOL` above?

I thought when something is deprecated that a new syntax must already exist and this would give me time to transition to a form that won't break in "SQL 2017+".

Origin:

[Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/ms143729)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misreading the deprecation notice. Specifically, you seem to be confusing DML (Data *Modification* Language) with DDL (Data *Definition* Language). What is being deprecated is the ability to use `ROWGUIDCOL` in `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` / `MERGE` statements:

```sql
-- DDL statement
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
  ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEWID()) ROWGUIDCOL,
  SomeColumn INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Test ([SomeColumn]) VALUES (1), (100);

SELECT * FROM #Test;

DECLARE @RowID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SELECT TOP 1 @RowID = tbl.[ID]
FROM   #Test tbl;

SELECT @RowID AS [RowToUpdate];

-- DML statement
UPDATE tmp
SET    tmp.[SomeColumn] += 2
FROM   #Test tmp
WHERE  ROWGUIDCOL = @RowID;

SELECT * FROM #Test;
```

If you run the above, only one row will be updated. This example shows that `ROWGUIDCOL` when used in a DML statement (not in a DDL statement) is dynamically replaced with the actual column marked as `ROWGUIDCOL`. And this is, in fact, why you are able (or required?) to mark a column as `ROWGUIDCOL` in a DDL statement: so that you (and other processes) can find it later :-).

Comment: This is correct. Yes, I was confusing DDL and DML.

Answer (score 0):

The document you pointed to is actually abundantly clear about what is deprecated:

> ROWGUIDCOL as a column name in **DML** statements.

The recommendation is to use `$rowguid`.

So for instance:

```
SELECT ROWGUIDCOL
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
```

is deprecated.  Use this instead:

```
SELECT $rowguid
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
```

The key is "DML" in the definition of what is being deprecated.  This doesn't affect DDL operations such as `CREATE TABLE`.